# Can't get Messages from ActiveMQ Queue

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm running ActiveMQ 5.14.5. I have a Queue with some Pending messages. Screenshot from the console:

[image]

There are no active consumers.

[image]

The console reports that there are 21651 messages. However if I try and view them, it appears to be empty:

[image]

Furthermore when I try to call `receive()` on my `org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnection` it blocks and receives no messages.

I'm fairly sure that there *are* messages there, and they should be retrieved. This used to work, and has stopped working.

Is there an explanation for this? There aren't any errors in the log.

Edit:

I'm using the Java client in Clojure. I didn't want to share it because it might confuse matters, but here it is. I'm using a Pooled factory in a couple of different threads. But I think the above example using the console is self-contained.

```
(let [factory (org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.
                 "Username"
                 "Password"
                 "URI")
      pooled-connection-factory (org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.)]
  (.setConnectionFactory pooled-connection-factory factory)
  (.start pooled-connection-factory)
  (with-open [connection (.createConnection factory)]
    (let [session (.createSession connection false, javax.jms.Session/AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
          destination (.createQueue session (:queue-name config))
          consumer (.createConsumer session destination)]
      (.start connection)
      (loop [message (.receive consumer)]
        (println (.getText ^org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage message))
        (recur (.receive consumer))))))
```

Comment: Message dequeued greater than enqueued ?? Strange, purge the queue and retry

Comment: Ah, I restarted. That explains the discrepancy in numbers.

Comment: Can you share your code?  I suspect you haven't called connection.start()

Comment: Sorry, the code's in Clojure but it's using the Java API. I didn't want to share it because, although it's simple, it might confuse things. I am calling `.start()` and *this code has worked before* in the past just fine. It has suddenly stopped working. Don't you agree that I should be able to see the messages in the web console?